# Disable click animation effect in recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to disable the animation on click events in recyclerview items but I should allow scrolling through the list.
This is my current code, but it doesn't work because I can't scroll up and down.
What am I missing?

```
binding.recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.SimpleOnItemTouchListener() {
      override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(recyclerView: RecyclerView, motionEvent: MotionEvent) = false
    })
```

Comment: what do you mean by disabling click event?  recycleview doesn't have any click by default

Comment: I mean, if you are not declaring that the items have click events, it's not necessary to do this. Or are you just trying to get rid of some click animation?

Comment: yes, exactly, I am trying to get rid of the animation. That's what I meant, sorry

Comment: Can you share some screenshot? on click and without click?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the item animator altogether on your xml:

```
recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
```

Or by code after declaring and initializing your recyclerView:

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null)
```

If that doesn't work, in your item.xml add to the parent layout:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: Can you post your recyclerview xml and your item.xml on your question?